Sending multi Params from angular to Spring (one of the params is a file )
I'm trying to send an http request containing multiple params to spring, one of the params is a file but i'm getting bad request error from the server, i'm sure i made a stupid mistake but still i need ur help
this is the angular side :
addNewRessource(formData:ressource,spaceId:number):Observable<any>{
      const data = new FormData();
      data.append('file', formData.fileData);
      data.append('name', formData.ressourceName);
      data.append('type', formData.ressourceType.toString());
      data.append('spaceId', spaceId.toString());
    return this.http.post(`${this.url}upload`,data)
  }

this is the Spring side :
  @PostMapping("/upload")
    public ResponseEntity<Ressource> uploadResource(
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                @RequestParam("name") String resourceName,
                @RequestParam("type") RessourceType resourceType,
            @RequestParam("spaceId") Long spaceId
    ) {
        try {
            Ressource savedResource = ressourceService.uploadResource(file, resourceName, resourceType, spaceId);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(savedResource);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        }
    }


I suggest using @RequestParam for the file and @PathVariable for resourceName, resourceType and spaceId, your Spring API should be :
@PostMapping("/upload")
    public ResponseEntity<Ressource> uploadResource(
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
            @PathVariable("name") String resourceName,
            @PathVariable("type") String resourceType,
            @PathVariable("spaceId") Long spaceId
    )

Also since you are sending resourceType and spaceId as a string from angular, they have to be a string also in your API, then you convert the params in spring side
In your angular request append concatenate the parameters in the http request url :
addNewRessource(formData:ressource,spaceId:number):Observable<any>{
      const data = new FormData();
      data.append('file', formData.fileData);
      return this.http.post(`${this.url}upload/${resourceName}/${resourceType.toString()}/${spaceId.toString()}`,data)
  }

